# How to add trigger for MouseUp in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, triggers, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I want to make my button (I define a `ControlTemplate` for a `Button`) to trigger my animation when mouse-up (clicked on the button and and left the mouse button). That's because `Button` doesn't have `VisualState` like `MouseUp` but only `Pressed` when it comes to clicking.

I want my animation to be executed without me holding the button, I just want to click and release.

Here is my code (you can see that I put  but it didn't make any impact:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="BorderOfTemplate" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                        <Border.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="1x">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".1" />
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="1x">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value=".1" />
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="1x">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-170" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Border.Triggers>

                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" />
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform" />
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>

                     <here some VisualStateManager>
                     </here some VisualStateManager>
enter code here
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979699.aspx), Silverlight's ordinary `EventTrigger` only supports the `Loaded` event.

However, using the `EventTrigger` from `System.Windows.Interactivity`, it seems you can use other events, for example **Click** or **MouseLeftButtonUp**. See this article for an example: [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125188/Using-EventTrigger-in-XAML-for-MVVM-No-Code-Behind)